# Go Router Builder gives error on building

Tags: flutter, flutter-go-router, build-runner

I have some simple pages and lists I want to navigate, they all work fine apart from when I add one layer deeper navigation after a list.

Here's the code for my routes:

```
part 'routes.g.dart';

final GlobalKey<NavigatorState> _shellNavigatorKey =
    GlobalKey<NavigatorState>(debugLabel: 'shell');

@TypedShellRoute<AppShellRoute>(routes: <TypedGoRoute<GoRouteData>>[
  TypedGoRoute<TodoGroupListRoute>(
      path: TodoGroupListRoute.path,
      routes: <TypedGoRoute<GoRouteData>>[
        TypedGoRoute<TodoGroupRoute>(
          path: TodoGroupRoute.path,
          routes: <TypedGoRoute<GoRouteData>>[
            TypedGoRoute<TodoRoute>(path: TodoRoute.path)
          ],
        )
      ]),
  TypedGoRoute<TodoListRoute>(path: TodoListRoute.path),
  TypedGoRoute<SettingsRoute>(path: SettingsRoute.path),
])
@immutable
class AppShellRoute extends ShellRouteData {
  const AppShellRoute();

  static final $navigatorKey = _shellNavigatorKey;

  @override
  Widget builder(BuildContext context, GoRouterState state, Widget navigator) {
    return AppShell(navigator);
  }
}

@immutable
class TodoGroupListRoute extends GoRouteData {
  const TodoGroupListRoute();
  static const path = '/todoGroupList';

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context, GoRouterState state) {
    return const TodoGroupListPage();
  }
}

@immutable
class TodoListRoute extends GoRouteData {
  const TodoListRoute();
  static const path = '/todoList';

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context, GoRouterState state) {
    return const TodoListPage();
  }
}

@immutable
class SettingsRoute extends GoRouteData {
  const SettingsRoute();
  static const path = '/settings';

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context, GoRouterState state) {
    return const SettingsPage();
  }
}

// ----------------------------------------------------------------------------

@immutable
class TodoGroupRoute extends GoRouteData {
  const TodoGroupRoute(this.todoGroupId);
  static const path = 'todoGroup/:todoGroupId';

  final String todoGroupId;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context, GoRouterState state) {
    return TodoGroupPage(todoGroupId);
  }
}

@immutable
class TodoRoute extends GoRouteData {
  const TodoRoute(this.todoId);
  static const path = 'todo/:todoId';

  final String todoId;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context, GoRouterState state) {
    return TodoPage(todoId);
  }
}
```

I'm getting this error:

```
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Starting Build
[INFO] Updating asset graph completed, took 2ms
[SEVERE] go_router_builder on lib/infrastructure/routes.dart:

Could not find a field for the path parameter "todoGroupId".
package:todo_list/infrastructure/routes.dart:90:7
   ╷
90 │ class TodoRoute extends GoRouteData {
   │       ^^^^^^^^^
   ╵
[INFO] Running build completed, took 511ms
[INFO] Caching finalized dependency graph completed, took 15ms
[SEVERE] Failed after 531ms
```

I simply want to navigate to the Todo Group page, select a Todo from the list which brings me to the Todo page. No idea why it's asking for the todoGroupId for the TodoRoute.

Works perfect with just the TodoRoute commented out.